# how can I set a parent div to make children maximum 3 per row for CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set each item inside of a parent div and given it a width property of 33%, thinking that therefore there can be only 3 per row

```
.item {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

this is the parent

```
.categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row-wrap;
}
```

My expectation is that only 3 items will be per row, as each of the categories are 33%, but the behaviour is that there are as many as can fit into each row, disregarding that rule, so I am understanding it wrong, if someone can point to the resource to look into about this or help explain it, thanks!

I have a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-ellis-cvvpu

Comment: typo.. use `item` in class name not `.item`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have set all classes in Home.js file like:

```
<div className=".item">
```

Instead of doing:

```
<div className="item">
```

Just remove the `.` in all `className` and your code will work fine.